# Parse JSON with jquery and add it to the textbox autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to build an autocomplete textbox. My script is as below in Razor View page:

```
@model AutoComplete.Models.Country
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryName, new { Class = "field" })
<div class="keys"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.field').keyup(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./js/" + $('.field').val(),
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

My controller method is:

```
public ActionResult SearchByKey(string keyword)
        {
            CountryContext db = new CountryContext();
            var result= db.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryName.Contains(keyword));
            return Json(result , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

My controller returns Json data as below:

```
[{"CountryId":"1","CountryName":"India"},
 {"CountryId":"2","CountryName":"Indonesia"}
]
```

I want to 1]**parse this data** and 2] **append it to the textbox** in the above view page. How can I do this?

Comment: You can cover the parsing aspect by adding `dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax()` parameters. That tells the function to expect a JSON formatted response.

Comment: @diggersworld No effect after adding datatype

Comment: What's the value of `result` in the `success` callback?

Comment: @Alexander When I alert result , it says [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: try `alert ($.parseJSON(result));` and tell us the result

Comment: @Saju It alerts null. But i can see my json data in firebug that is returned from controller.

Comment: You can't alert an object, that much should be obvious. Use the console (F12) for this sort of thing, and console.log(result) to see it it's an object or most likely just a string. Then try to parse it, and see if there are any errors, which there most likely is, and that means that you are not returning proper JSON.

Comment: @Kumar: Why did you add a tag for that plugin? I don't see any indication that OP is using it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a simpler solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('.field').keyup(function () {
        $.getJson("./js/" + $('.field').val(), function (result) {
            // result should contain the parsed JSON
        });
    });

});
```

Examples can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

NOTE:
The second selector for '.field' should probably be replaced with $(this), .val() will be retrieved for *every* tag with a 'field' class

Or even something like:

```
    $.on('keyup', '.field', function () {
        $.getJson("./js/" + $(this).val(), function (result) {
            // result should contain the parsed JSON
        });
    });
```

Haven't tested the code though, just out of my head :)

Comment: I wanted to illustrate usage of .getJson as alternative to .ajax, in order to don't have to specify content-types etc. Furthermore, the answer by Simon below doesn't really make sense; the data should not need to be parsed (parseJSON) for each element in the array

Answer (score 0):

Parse the returned string to make it an object, then somehow iterate over the object and insert the values where you'd like to have them inserted :

```
$(function() {
    $('.field').on('keyup', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "./js/" + this.value
        }).done(function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                 $(element).append(value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It shows an error in firebug TypeError: object is null
[Break On This Error]  

length = object.length,

Comment: It sounds like you are not returning proper formatted JSON from the serverside.

Comment: @adeneo $(element).append(value) should probably be $(element).append(value.CountryName); or something alike?

Comment: @BhushanFirake if you put console.log(data); inside the 'done' callback, does it output a JSON array/object or a string?

Comment: @thaJeztah - You're probably right, but it was meant more as a guide on how to iterate and insert values, as I'm not sure the OP really knows what is returned here.

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes, it does return json as given in the question

Comment: @thaJeztah [Object { CountryId=

"1"

,  CountryName=

"India"

}, Object { CountryId=

"2"

,  CountryName=

"Indonesia"

}] in console

Comment: Looks like an array with objects, and in the example in the answer above thaJeztah's suggestion should work, but you always have to console log objects like this, and look at the structure, then it's easy to access the right property inside the object.

Comment: @adeneo Yes , it is an array of objects as in question.

Comment: Then, in the example above, the $.parseJSON(data) line should not be required. (I've added the modified example)

Comment: On a further note. There are excellent plugins for jQuery that provide autocomplete functionality, for example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead